# Insect ID, Ecuador

Tags: species-identification, entomology

Picture was taken in the Ecuadorian Amazon in January 2019, during the day, elevation about 300 meters. The size was not recorded but might be no bigger than a housefly judging from the photo. It appears to be a leafhopper of subfamily Gyponinae. Any additional info on the genus or species would be appreciated. [image: leafhopper-like insect]

Comment: I am no entomologist, but that looks like it may be a type of cicada. Is it [one of these](https://www.cicadamania.com/cicadas/category/locations/ecuador/) perhaps?

Comment: Hi, terdon. Thanks for the comment. The bug was quite small, and does look like a cicada, but a very small one. From some info I received, I think this might be a leafhopper. Leafhoppers are relatives of cicadas.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the size since that will likely help identify it. Also tell us what kind of environment you found it in (jungle, yes, but was it in the canopy? On a tree bark? On the forest floor? Did it have a nest you could see?) The more details you give, the likelier it is someone will be able to identify it.

Comment: Well, it was taken about a month ago, along with about 600 other subjects, so what I know about it is pretty well in the photo. It was on a leaf. It was small compared to the leaf, although I don't have a record of the size of the leaf. I'm satisfied that it is a kind of leafhopper, subfamily Gyponinae. That is a varied group, but that is fine for now.

Comment: Please ***[edit]*** your question and include these details. Comments are easy to miss, hard to read and can be deleted without warning. You want the next person to read your question (who might actually know what they're talking about and not just be stabbing in the dark like I am) to have all the details easily accessible.